# Can't activate Windows 10 after reset from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I have reset my **windows 10** HP laptop with clean my personal files option, due to performance issues. Now it refuses to activate my **windows 10** again and says that the issue is with that I'm behind a proxy server with authentication requirements but I'm not.

Here is a photo :

[image]

```
Also I tried resetting my product key :
```

[image]

Error code: 0xd0000272

What should I do now? Also consider that I've upgraded from `windows 7 to 10` in the first place.

Comment: Use the phone activation

Answer (score 1):

Look at the picture is states

> "Our activation server is down. We're working on it to fix the
>   problem"

So this is an server issue in Microsoft that we and you can't control. Try it again later and if you still have issues, phone the Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

If the computers width error 0xd0000272 are in LAN environment, only one thing  to activation  help me .
Disable LAN connection and then, connect computer to the internet over the mobile phone ( usb mobile HotSpot option) , or another connection (neighbor  ..... ) . Not WI-FI in the same network help - only different network (use the computer , take it home and connect to internet and activate .